# Joomla DB Write

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Does a Joomla site write anything (session etc.) to the Db upon browsing (no logins just plain browsing)? I would like to make my DB read-only for maintenance purposes.

Comment: So, make the db read-only, fire up your browser and tell us what happens.

Comment: I already did and it doesn't work. I want to know the reason. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an out-of-the box Joomla installation stores session information in the DB. However, if you have XCache or Memcached support installed on your server, you can change the handler to use something else. In the backend, go to Site > Global Configuration, then click the System link. At the bottom of the right hand column, there's a setting where you can change the session handler from 'Database' to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yea , Joomla keeps sessions for guest users too. So whenever a user visits the site , one record will be added to the user table. So it is better to take the site offline instead of making the database read only.